# Java DOM: Number of first child nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have XML like this

```
<Cars>
    <Car name="abc" title="car length" length="20" type="type1" />
    <Car name="abc" title="car length" length="20" type="type2">
        <Car name="abc" title="car length" length="20" type="type1" />
        <Car name="abc" title="car length" length="20" type="type1" />
        <Car name="abc" title="car length" length="20" type="type1" />
    </Car> 
</Cars>
```

---

```
Element carNode = ...;
NodeList carList = carNode.getElementsByTagName("Car");
carList.getLength();
```

`carList.getLength();` gives length of all descendant nodes. So in this case it gives 5.
As there are 2 first child nodes of **Cars**, how can I get that length i.e. 2?

Comment: why you want this? I think it's not possible getElementsByTagName() returns matching tagname so,it will return every time 5 length.

Comment: This is requirement. XML tags names cannot be changed. Is there no way to return length first child nodes? not also descendant childs.

Comment: you have to use iterator,i think there is no shortcut!

Answer (score 2):

That only goes by own code or XPath.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Cars/Car");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)  expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```